# Write Powershell function, that can be called with pipeline input AND "normal" input"

Tags: powershell

I've a simple function:

```
    function Write-Log {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            # Lines to log
            [Parameter(Mandatory , ValueFromPipeline )]
            [AllowEmptyString()]
            $messages
        )

        process {
            Write-Host $_ 
        }
    }
```

Based on `ValueFromPipeline` in can use the function with pipeline input, e.g.

```
 "a","b", "c" | Write-Log
 a
 b
 c
```

That's ok. But if I want to use my function in that way:

```
 Write-Log -message "a", "b", "c"
```

the automatic `$_` variable is empty, and nothing is printed.

I also found these two stackoverflow links:

- [Handling pipeline and parameter input in a Powershell function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885349/how-do-i-write-a-powershell-script-that-accepts-pipeline-input)
- [How do I write a PowerShell script that accepts pipeline input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593656/handling-pipeline-and-parameter-input-in-a-powershell-function)

Both of them suggest the following pattern:

```
  function Write-Log {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            # Lines to log
            [Parameter(Mandatory , ValueFromPipeline )]
            [AllowEmptyString()]
            $messages
        )

        process {
            foreach ($message in $messages){
                Write-Host $message
            }
        }
    }
```

Above pattern works for my use case. But from my point of view is feels weird to call `foreach` in the `process´ block, since (as far as I've understood) the process block is called for every pipeline item. As there a better cleaner way to write functions supporting both use cases?

Thx.

Comment: The way you say 'feels weird' is actually the way that Microsoft examples do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way you have to do it if you want to pass an array to a parameter like

```
Write-Log -Messages a,b,c
```

Otherwise you can only do

```
Write-Log -Messages a
```

You can still pipe an array in without the foreach:

```
Echo a b c | Write-Log
```

I appreciate cmdlets that can do both, like get-process.